# How to solve this error: riak_client: RuntimeError: The NetHTTP HTTP backend cannot used

Tags: riak

I'm new to Riak , Here's the ruby code I tried in irb:

```
irb(main):002:0> c = Riak::Client.new
=> #<Riak::Client http://127.0.0.1:8098>
irb(main):003:0> obj = c['videos']['first']
RuntimeError: The NetHTTP HTTP backend cannot be used. Please check its requirements.
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/riak-client-0.9.8/lib/riak/client.rb:247:in `http'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/riak-client-0.9.8/lib/riak/client.rb:276:in `backend'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/riak-client-0.9.8/lib/riak/bucket.rb:102:in `get'
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

How could I solve this problem?

Thanks,  and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error message because I was specifying a port number different from the one Riak was using as such:

```
client  = Riak::Client.new(:port => 8091, :http_backend => :Excon)
```

Maybe Riak is running on a different port for you or not running at all.  To fix this, I just removed the port number:

```
client = Riak::Client.new(:http_backend => :Excon)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says that it's missing the requirements.
You should install them according to [documentation](https://github.com/basho/riak-ruby-client/) or maybe just try another backend.